# How to strip date in csv output using shell script?

Tags: bash, ksh, aix

I have a few csv extracts that I am trying to fix up the date on, they are as follows:

```
"Time Stamp","DBUID"
2016-11-25T08:28:33.000-8:00,"5tSSMImFjIkT0FpiO16LuA"
```

The first column is always the "Time Stamp", I would like to convert this so it only keeps the date "2016-11-25" and drops the "T08:28:33.000-8:00".

The end result would be..

```
"Time Stamp","DBUID"
2016-11-25,"5tSSMImFjIkT0FpiO16LuA"
```

There are plenty of files with different dates.

Is there a way to do this in ksh? Some kind of for each loop to loop through all the files and replace the long time-stamp and leave just the date?

Comment: Using `sed` cant be a solution?

Comment: You're sure you're comfortable with losing that much precision on your dates?  `2016-11-25` could be any time from 13 hours before to 11 hours after that date, depending on time zone.

Comment: Also, what have you tried? I don't see any code for us to help you fix.

Comment: Yes I am OK with loosing the precision as I only need the day the extract ran (we run it once every month) so day precision is fine for our needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sed:

```
$ sed '2,$s/T[^,]*//' file
"Time Stamp","DBUID"
2016-11-25,"5tSSMImFjIkT0FpiO16LuA"
```

How it works:

```
2,$           # Skip header (first line) removing this will make a
              # replacement on the first line as well.
   s/T[^,]*// # Replace everything between T (inclusive) and , (exclusive)
              # `[^,]*' Matches everything but `,' zero or more times
```

Comment: I went with this because I am already using sed to do something else, so adding another pipe/sed to the existing command was easiest. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @v3rd1ct You can use `sed 'first' | sed 'second'`, or `sed -e 'first' -e 'second'` of `sed 'first;second'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using a standard aix utility,

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR>1{sub(/T.*$/,"",$1)}1' file > file.cln && mv file.cln file
```

**output**

```
"Time Stamp","DBUID"
2016-11-25,"5tSSMImFjIkT0FpiO16LuA"
```

(but I no longer have access to an  aix environment, so only tested with my local `awk`).

`NR>1` skips the header line, and the `sub()` is limited to only the first field (up to the first comma). The trailing `1` char is `awk` shorthand for `{print $0}`.

If your data layout changes and you get extra commas in your data, this may required fixing.

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -i "s/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\).*,/\1-\2-\3,/" file.csv
```

**Output:**

```
"Time Stamp","DBUID"
2016-11-25,"5tSSMImFjIkT0FpiO16LuA"
```

`-i` edit files inplace

`s` substitute

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect job for `awk`, but unlike the previous answer, I recommend using the `substring` function.

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1{$1 = substr($1,1,10)} {print $0}' file.txt
```

Explanation

> **-F,**: The -F flag sets a field separator, in this case a comma
>
> **NR > 1**: Ignore the first row
>
> **$1**: Refers to the first field
>
> **$1 = substr($1,1,10)**: Sets the first field to the first 10 characters of the field. In the example, this is the date portion
>
> **print $0**: This will print the entire row